# Como criar arquivo png para gráficos múltiplos usando x11 no R?

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, geany

Consegui plotar e gerar arquivos (png) dos gráficos simples, mas no caso de vários gráficos na mesma janela (como no caso do x11) eu não consigo salvar o arquivo no diretório.

```
png(filename="box_sv_sst_mean.png",width=2034,height=2034,units="px",pointsize=12,bg="white",res=300)
x11(width = 14, height = 7)
par(mfrow = c(1,2),mar=c(5,4,2,2),oma=c(0,0,2,0))
boxplot(SSTmean~year,ylab="temperatura °C",xlab="ano")
boxplot(SSTmean~month,ylab="temperatura °C",xlab="mês")
title("SST Média",outer=TRUE,cex.main=2)
dev.off()
```

É possível salvar o gráfico usando `png(filename=nome_do_grafico.png)` e `dev.off()`? Onde está o erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x11()` é uma função para criar uma nova janela gráfica no R.
Para vários gráficos na mesma janela, você usa a opção `mfrow = c(x, y)` dentro da função `par()` (O que você já está usando).

**Solução**:
Seu problema será resolvido, provavelmente, removendo a linha `x11(width = 14, height = 7)`.

**Motivo**: Quando você salva um gráfico com `png()`, você está abrindo uma nova janela gráfica. Então se você usa `x11()` após `png()` você está abrindo uma nova janela, desativando a função `png()`.

Comment: Muito obrigada! eu ja havia tentado eliminar a linha do x11 e funcionou!